# How to remove Blank Factors from ggplot bar which has NAs

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio, bar-chart

I want to remove "Antarctica" from my ggplor bar, I tried using na.rm and na.omit but I still see Antarctica bar in my graph. Data and output attached here. Can someone please help Input Data is attached Here

[image: 1]

```
Bar1<- 
ggplot(ContinentMaster,aes(x=ContinentMaster$Continent,y=NoOfcountries,
    fill=NoOfcountries,label = NoOfcountries,na.rm = TRUE))

Bar1+  geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="Blue",fill="LightGreen",size=0.5)+
geom_text(size=3, position = position_stack(vjust = 1.05))+
xlab(" ")+
ylab("No Of Countries")+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 60),breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60))+
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))+
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Output Graph

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), don't attach images of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code will subset your data frame, keeping only the rows that have a value for ContinentMaster$NoOfcountries (i.e. are not NA):

`ContinentMaster <- ContinentMaster[!is.na(ContinentMaster$NoOfcountries), ]`

I hope that is helpful for you.